# How do I determine the distance between v and PQ when v =[2,1,2] and PQ = [1,0,3]? P = [0,0,0] Q = [1,0,3]

Tags: calculus

What I have tried already: d = |v||PQ|sin("Theta")

Now, I need to determine what theta is, so I set up a position on a makeshift graph, the graph I made was on the xy plane only as the z plane complicates things needlessly for finding theta. So, I ended up with an acute angle, and if the angle is acute, then I have to find theta which according to dot product facts is greater than 0.

I do not have access to theta, so I used the same princples from cross dots. u * v = |u||v|cos("theta") but in this case, u and v are PQ and v. A vector is a vector, right?

so now I have theta = acos((v*PQ)/(|v||PQ))

with that I get (4sqrt(10))/15 = 32.5125173162 in degrees, so the angle is 32.5125173162 degrees.

So, now that I have theta, I plug it into my distance formula |v||PQ|sin(32.5125173162)

3*sqrt(10)*sin(32.5125173162) = 5.0990195136

or for the sake of simplicity, 5.1

I however want to know if this question is correct.

If it is NOT correct, what can I do to correct it? At what points did I use incorrect information?

This is not a question with a definitive answer in the back of the book, its a question on the side of a page that said: "try this!"

Comment: Either you forgot to mention the programming language you're working on or you missed the "Post your question" button at https://math.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: So `v` and `PQ` are both vectors?

Comment: I think all you need to do here is use the Pythagorean Theorem for 3-dimensions:  `d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with this question.

1. From the context it looks like you mean for both v and PQ to be vectors.  The "distance" between two vectors is an awkward (not well defined) question because vectors are not position bound.
2. You are using the cross product formula and I have no idea why:

   |AxB| = |A||B|Sin(theta)
3. I think what you are actually trying to do is calculate the distance between the terminal points of the vectors, (2, 1, 2) and (1, 0, 3).  Just use the Pythagorean Theorem (extended to 3D) for this.

   d = sqrt( (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 + (z1 - z2)^2 )

   d = sqrt( (2 - 1)^2 + (1 - 2)^2 + (2 - 3)^2 )

   d = sqrt( 1^2 + (-1)^2 + (-1)^2 )

   d = sqrt(3)

Edit:

If what you need really is the magnitude of the cross product, |AxB| then just find the cross product (using the determinant) and then calculate the magnitude of the result.  There is no need for the formula you were using.